# VBS close all chrome tabs

Tags: google-chrome, vbscript

I am trying to create this:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'Chrome.exe'")

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
For Each objProcess in colProcessList
oShell.Run "taskkill /im chrome.exe", , True
Next

Dim iURL 
Dim objShell

iURL = "www.google.com.au"

set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1
```

The code works, but if there are too many chrome tabs open, it doesn't close all tabs. There is also sometimes an error message in closing tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is opening Chrome in `incognito` mode so that you don't see the `Restore Session` error.

```
Dim objExec, objShell, iURL

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExec = objShell.Exec("tasklist /fi " & Chr(34) & "imagename eq chrome.exe" & Chr(34))
If Not InStr(1, objExec.StdOut.ReadAll(), "INFO: No tasks", vbTextCompare) Then
    objShell.Run "taskkill /f /t /im chrome.exe", 0, True
End If

iURL = "www.google.com.au"
objShell.Run "chrome.exe -incognito " & iURL

Set objExec = Nothing : Set objShell = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help!